# Invalid date using moment javascript and DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, momentjs

This happens using dateTimePicker and moment.js:

[image]

If I use this line code:

```
 console.info($('#inp_date_time_'+value.fila+'_id').val());
```

print this date format:

> 04/09/2015 08:31

then If I use this line code:

```
moment($('#inp_date_time_'+value.fila+'_id').val()).format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss');
```

print this date format:

> 2015-09-04 08:31:00

and it's ok, but If I select a day more bigger that 12 (example : 13/09/2015)

I have "invalid date" , I think that take the days like months , or I don't know.

[image]

How can I fix this?, sorry my english.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option would be to specify `dateFormat` when creating a `moment` object. So replace `moment($('#inp_date_time_'+value.fila+'_id').val()).format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss');` with `moment($('#inp_date_time_'+value.fila+'_id').val(),, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss')`;