# Javascript time calculation issue on Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I am facing issue in my web application where I'm calculating start time and end time difference, it works on Chrome v.57, Firefox v.52.

It's failing on Firefox v.45 (CentOS 6.6) and I check the CentOS 6.6 repo it is the latest version available on it.

Can someone please tell me how to calculate the difference of time so that it works on all browser?

I am using bootstrap-datetimepicker in my web app where user pick the time of their choice.

```
var start_time = '2017-04-11 23:29:41 -07:00',
    end_time = '2017-04-10 23:29:41 -07:00',
    start_time_js =  start_time.split(' '),
    end_time_js =  start_time.split(' ');
start_time_js = new Date(start_time_js[0] + ' ' + start_time_js[1]);
end_time_js = new Date(end_time_js[0] + ' ' + end_time_js[1]);
elapsed_time = end_time_js.getTime() - start_time_js.getTime();

if(elapsed_time < 0) {
    console.log('Start time must be less then end time')
}
```

Screenshot of debug mode in Firefox 45, Note that `start_time_js` says `Invalid Date`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works for me on Firefox 52 on Windows 7. What is the value of `start_time_js.getTime()` in your environment?

Comment: Yes, it works on Firefox 52, but the issue is on Firefox 45 as mentioned in question.

Comment: Can you use external libraries?

Comment: no I can not add external libs ...need to do it in pure JS only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use external libraries you have to parse by yourself the input and then you can use [`new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) constructor.

Note that months are 0 indexed.

Here a working sample:

```js
function getDateFromString(input){
  var split = input.split(' ');
  var datePart = split[0].split('-');
  var timePart = split[1].split(':');
  var dt = new Date(datePart[0], datePart[1]-1, datePart[2], timePart[0], timePart[1], timePart[2]);
  return dt;
}

var start_time = '2017-04-11 23:29:41 -07:00',
    end_time = '2017-04-10 23:29:41 -07:00';

var dtStart = getDateFromString(start_time);
var dtEnd = getDateFromString(end_time);

var elapsed_time = dtEnd.getTime() - dtStart.getTime();

if(elapsed_time < 0) {
  console.log('Start time must be less then end time')
}
```

One of the best way to handle JavaScript dates cross browser is using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com). In your case, you can use [moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)/[`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) to compare moment objects.

Your code could be like the following:

```js
var start_time = '2017-04-11 23:29:41 -07:00',
  end_time = '2017-04-10 23:29:41 -07:00',
  start_time_js =  start_time.split(' '),
  end_time_js =  end_time.split(' ');

var mStart = moment(start_time_js[0] + ' ' + start_time_js[1]);
var mEnd = moment(end_time_js[0] + ' ' + end_time_js[1]);

if(mEnd.isBefore(mStart)) {
  console.log('Start time must be less then end time')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look here maybe helm, and include cdn from above
  [Invalid date using moment javascript and DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503910/invalid-date-using-moment-javascript-and-datetimepicker)
  [eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker invalid date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320809/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker-invalid-date-conversion)

  Some of / are not working in localhost mode

Comment: All JS/CSS files are loaded properly in browser